# raising onkeypress element when input value is null

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am developing a chat application with user-typing and user-erasing functionality  but i am having difficulties in calling a function when the textarea chat input is null( when the user erase all what he typed )

```
  var msg=$("#chat_input").val();
 if ((e.which== 8 || e.keyCode == 8) && (msg.trim() == "" || msg.length <= 1)) {
    // call the function 

 }
```

when a user type one letter and then erase it the function is not called and this `if` statement is false 
 how can i fix this

Comment: Have you tried using the `keyup` event instead, and/or the `input` event? Also, don't forget to allow for when the user deletes text with the mouse and/or Edit menu. Note that if you bind the event handler with jQuery you don't need to test `e.keyCode` because jQuery will ensure that `e.which` is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backspacing the last character or only having new lines or spaces means `this.value` will return `false`

```
$('#chat_input').keyup(function(e){
    if (e.which == 8 && this.value == false) {

    }
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BrianDillingham/vwwzL7gu/)

---

`value` is `false` if is just a space, newline etc, so you don't need `trim()`

```
( msg.length <= 1 ) // = true when second to last or last
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this by using implicit true/false checks

```
 var msg=$("#chat_input").val();
 if (e.which== 8 && (!msg || !msg.trim())) {
    // call the function 

 }
```

`!msg` will return true if `msg` is undefined or null and `!msg.trim()` will return true if `msg.trim()` is an empty string.